# How can i print $row array data into diferent parts of my webpage?

Tags: php, html

Usually when you do the basic php excercises you just use the following to print data on a blank page:

```
<?php
include('../includes/dbh.php');

$titulo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['titulo']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM proyectos WHERE proyect_name='$titulo'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$queryResults = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($queryResults > 0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "<div>".$row['proyect_name']. "
        </div>";


    }
}
?>
```

My question is, if I try to separate and `echo` out `$row` `proyect_name` in another part of the webpage nothing happens. I used both `echo` and `var_dump` and yes, the query works but it just doesn't print anything. I am new to this so yes, it may be obvious to you but not to me. I think it may be the `while` loop, but I do not know how to "blend it in".

Comment: seriously look at template engines for mixing dynamic and static content

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
include('../includes/dbh.php');

$titulo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['titulo']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM proyectos WHERE proyect_name='$titulo'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$queryResults = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$data=array();

if($queryResults > 0){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "<div>".$row['proyect_name']. "
        </div>";
        $data[] = $row;


    }
}

foreach($data as value) {
echo $value; 
}
// OR
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
echo $key . " - " . $value;
}
?>
```

Set variable before loop then add $row data to it then loop it out with a foreach loop Does this work??

Comment: He will only get the last selected row, since the loop ends with it, Unless you meant to use `.=` and he wanted to store it as a `string`.

Comment: Problem Fixed :) @Toleo

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, i know that may have been too dumb to ask but i really couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

Use [mysqli_fetch_array()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) - [Example](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php#95881)

So in your case it would be

```
<?php
include('../includes/dbh.php');

$titulo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET['titulo']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM proyectos WHERE proyect_name='$titulo'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$queryResults = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($queryResults > 0){
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array()){
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        echo "<div>".$row['proyect_name']."</div>";
    }
}
?>
```